# Angular 2 / 4 - How to use Protractor with mocked backend?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, protractor, circleci

I have an Angular 4 app. Nothing fancy, a simple corporate website. Now I've written a basic test for Protractor in these two files:

**app.po.ts**

```
import { browser, element, by } from 'protractor';

export class AppPage {

    public navigateTo() {
        return browser.get('/');
    }

    public getTitleText() {
        return element(by.css('my-app h1')).getText();
    }
}
```

**app.e2e-spec.ts**

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';

describe('My App', () => {

    let page: AppPage;

    beforeEach(() => {
        page = new AppPage();
    });

    it('should display the page title', () => {
        page.navigateTo();
        expect<any>(page.getTitleText()).toEqual('My Title');
    });
});
```

This worked until I recently implemented a WordPress REST API into the app. This API is running on another local server and the Angular app is making requests to the API via Angular's built-in `Http` functions. When running Protractor locally together with the WordPress server everything works.

But now I run my tests through CircleCI and get the error:

```
Failed: Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost:49152/.If this is not an Angular application, you may need to turn off waiting for Angular.
```

Point is, it **is** an Angular application. I suspect this error occurs because there is no backend REST API server running.

**Question**

How do I run Protractor tests (on e.g. Circle CI) with a mocked backend and how do I mock this backend?

Comment: Try adding `browser.ignoreSynchronization= true;` to make Protractor not wait for Angular on the webpage.

Comment: I came across this solution, but because my Angular app resolves initial data, I can't access HTML nodes on the page using this approach.